# Inverse of adjoint action?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Given the adjoint action $\text{ad}_AX=AX-XA$, is there an inverse adjoint action $\text{ad}^{-1}_A$ such that

$$\text{ad}^{-1}_A(\text{ad}_AX)=X?$$

Comment: Maybe you want to clarify what the adjoint action acts on, i.e. $X \in \; \color{red}{?}$

Comment: What about those $X$ for which $AX = XA$?  How do you undo $\operatorname{ad}_A(X)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Linear Algebra exercise. A linear map has a (left) inverse iff ...